# FileNotFoundError: Heroku can't read a file that exists and runs locally

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Python script to Heroku. Heroku gives me the following error in the logs:
My logs show the following error:

```
2021-05-26T11:02:31.302619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/scripts/gif_text.py", line 24, in make_gif
2021-05-26T11:02:31.302775+00:00 app[web.1]: with open('../data/lyrics.csv', 'r') as f:
2021-05-26T11:02:31.302832+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/lyrics.csv'
```

And locally, the piece of code which is causing the problem runs absolutely fine. Here it is:

```
  # Columns to Arrays
    with open('../data/lyrics.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            michael_harry.append(row.get('michael_harry'))
```

I then tried using `os.path.abspath()` instead, and changed how the files are being read to:

```
 # Columns to Arrays
    with open(os.path.abspath("data/lyrics.csv"), 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            michael_harry.append(row.get('michael_harry'))
```

This is what Heroku gives me now:

```
2021-05-26T11:19:21.140815+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/scripts/gif_text.py", line 24, in make_gif
2021-05-26T11:19:21.141019+00:00 app[web.1]: with open(os.path.abspath("data/lyrics"), 'r') as f:
2021-05-26T11:19:21.141024+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/data/lyrics'
```

And this is what happens locally:

```py
  File "D:\Data Projects\Automated Newsletter\scripts\gif_text.py", line 24, in make_gif
    with open(os.path.abspath("data/lyrics.csv"), 'r') as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Data Projects\\Automated Newsletter\\scripts\\data\\lyrics.csv'
```

How do I fix this? `lyrics.csv` definitely exists.

This is my directory structure:

```
 Newsletter/
├─ data/
│ ├─ .keep
│ └─ lyrics.csv
├─ models/
│ ├─ .keep
│ ├─ data.json
└─ scripts/
  ├─ gif_text.py
  ├─ item.txt
  ├─ markov/
  │ ├─ lyrics.py
  │ └─ reconstitute.py
```

Comment: what happens with `with open(os.path.abspath("../data/lyrics.csv"), 'r') as f:`?. Also, just to be 100% sure: `heroku run cat data/lyrics.csv`

Comment: also, I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471006/9267296) answers your question